# Service is unavailable

Tags: android, mobile-application, error-logging, neutrino

What should I do ?

I am using neutrino+ app to gain followers on Instagram but now the app won't login and will show me this message "the service is unavailable, update the application and try a little bit later "

and so you know my application is updated to the latest version

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the app?

Comment: @elbrant I tried it I have other accounts working perfectly on a clone app for nutrino  but the problem occurred for this account and I didn't get banned